# OnAuthorization not calling my PUT and post call

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have below code for authentication its working fine on get call `isValid.Result true` Get Call Working fine But its not call my controller PUT and POST call, I add debugger on my post and put call. But its not calling my post and put function?

```
  public class HMAuthentication : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, string> allowedApps = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        private readonly UInt64 requestMaxAgeInSeconds = 300;  //5 mins
        private readonly string authenticationScheme = "aa";
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
  var isValid = isValidRequest(requests, APPId, incomingBase64Signature, nonce, requestTimeStamp);

                if (isValid.Result)
                {
                    var currentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(APPId), null);                   
                }
}
}
```

GET CALL WORKING FINE

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class InfoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IUserService _info;

        public InfoController (IUserService info)
        {
            _info= info;
        }
     [HttpGet("GetInfo/{Id}")]
                public async Task<UserBase> GetInfo(int Id)
                {
                    return await _info.GetInfo(Id);
                }

PUT CALL

     [HttpPut]
            [Route("UpdateParent")]
            public async Task<int>  UpdateParent([FromBody] parent parentInfo)
            {
                return await _info.UpdateParent(parentInfo);
            }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new HMAuthentication ())).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem might be `[Route("UpdateParent")]` attribute. But I can't say much without the routeConfig. Perhaps a quick fix you could avail in case of bad routing is by adding an explicit route for this request and see if the authentication works properly. Here's a sample:

Add this to routeConfig.cs file found under AppStart folder:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UpdateParentHandler",
    url: "api/InfoController/UpdateParent",
    defaults: new { controller = "InfoController", action = "UpdateParent" }
);
```

PS: HardCoding routes is not good practice. However, you can use this as a temporary fix while you work around your problem! Cheers :)